# Why is this variable undefined in the function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have the sample code:

```js
var t = 20;
function test () {
  console.log(t);
    var t = 100;
}
test();
```

The result will be `undefined`. I thought `t` was global variable, so why, when I log it, is it `undefined`?

Comment: Remove `var` from the `t` inside the function.

Answer (score 5):

The scope of a variable is the reason why you're seeing this. From the [MDN documentation on `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> #### var hoisting
>
> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, **declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top**. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

Variables in JavaScript are *function-scoped*, meaning they only exist in the function. Since variable declarations are processed before any execution of code, they are declared are the beginning of the enclosing function-scope. This "pre-processing" is called "hoisting", as the declaration is hoisted up to the beginning of the enclosing function-scope. Since you redeclare `t` inside the function, it's declared at the beginning of the function (because variables are function-scoped) and is equivalent to this:

```
var t = 20;
function test () {
    var t;
    console.log(t);
    t = 100;
}
test();
```

Since `t` is never given a value before you assign it after the logging, it's `undefined`. The solution is to remove the `var` redeclaration. Thus, no declaration of a variable is seen in the function and nothing is hoisted.

---

Note that this hoisting procedure is the same reason why you can use function declarations before they're defined:

```js
foo(); //logs "foo called!"

function foo() {
    console.log("foo called!");
}
```

Function **declarations** (and *only* declarations) are hoisted like variables (but instead, the whole declaration is hoisted, not just the name). Thus, the function is declared before any execution happens, and when the code is run, `foo` is called as it's already declared.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

What this means is that your function's *declaration* of a new `t` variable is effectively performed at the opening of the function.  This immediately obscures the "global" `t` variable with the local one.  However, the line of code which sets a *value* to that new `t` variable doesn't execute until after you log to the console.  So the default value is `undefined`.

Perhaps not the most intuitive feature of JavaScript in this example, I'll admit.  But at the same time it highlights the importance of clarity in your code.  Having two variables of the same name even *attempt* to be accessible in the same scope is a potential source for bugs.  It would be better to give them different names.

Comment: Darn. I just realized that we basically used the same source and quote... sorry about that...

Comment: @AndrewLi: It's not a race, a good answer is a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`t` is both global and local.

When you are inside a function there is something called `scope`. This means you can declare variables with the same names as global ones and they will actually be completely different. Now notice where you place `console.log()`. If you did not decalre a variable `t` inside your function you would log 20 however you did so the function is concerned with the function's t. But you are logging before the t was declared!

```js
var t = 20;
function test () {    
    console.log(t);
}
test();
```

```js
var t = 20;
function test () {
    console.log(t);
    var t = 100;
}
test();
```

Your code is equivalent to: (the var is moved to the top without being defined. Something called hoisting.)

```js
var t = 20;
function test () {
    var t;
    t = 100;
     console.log(t);
}
test();
```